# Oracle 19c jdbc driver doesn't support schema names bigger than 30 bytes

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

According to Oracle's 19c [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA):

> The schema name can be 128 bytes, the table name can be 128 bytes, and the column name can be 128 bytes.

However, I'm facing this issue whenever I try to use a schema name bigger than 30 bytes:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setSchema(PhysicalConnection.java:9462)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setSchema(ProxyConnection.java:460)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setSchema(HikariProxyConnection.java)
```

The driver used is:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

It looks like the driver is not supporting longer object names introduced as per 12c version, any clues if this is somehow configurable? Could it also perhaps be some AWS RDS specific issue?

On SQL Developer using same jdbc url:

```
SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'compatible';

NAME       | VALUE
-------------------
compatible | 19.0.0

ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG_SCHEMA_NAME;

Session altered.
```

**UPDATE:**
After decompiling the driver code this is what I see:

```
public void setSchema(String schema) throws SQLException {
    try {
        String quoted = "\"[^\u0000\"]{0,28}\"";
        String unquoted = "(\\p{javaLowerCase}|\\p{javaUpperCase})(\\p{javaLowerCase}|\\p{javaUpperCase}|\\d|_|\\$|#){0,29}";
        String idPat = "(" + quoted + ")|(" + unquoted + ")";
        SQLException var10000;
        SQLException var9;
        if (schema == null) {
            var10000 = var9 = (SQLException)((SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68).fillInStackTrace());
            throw var10000;
        } else if (!schema.matches(idPat)) {
            var10000 = var9 = (SQLException)((SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68).fillInStackTrace());
            throw var10000;
        } else {
            String sql = "alter session set current_schema = " + schema;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                stmt = this.createStatement();
                stmt.execute(sql);
    ...
}
```

Meaning that the driver is hardcoded to accept only 30 chars. So it seems to be a **bug in the Oracle JDBC driver** implementation. Any ideas for alternatives?

Comment: Just at your link: *The maximum length of identifier names depends on the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter.: .... **·** If COMPATIBLE is set to a value lower than 12.2, then names must be from 1 to 30 bytes long with these exceptions*

Comment: And also it may depend on you [database character set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-EA913CC8-C5BA-4FB3-A1B8-882734AF4F43), because: *Oracle Database uses the database character set for: ... Identifiers such as table names, column names, and PL/SQL variables*. After you've passed SQL statement to the database it is no longer in programming language semantics, so texts are in DB character set

Comment: COMPATIBLE is already 19.0

Comment: And what about charset? `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`?

Comment: Personally, I think having object names greater than 30 characters is insane.  Any sane, reasonable, rigorously applied naming standard should produce readable, meaningful object names well under the 30-character limit.  I understand wanting to answer the technical question here - from an academic point.  But from a practical point, avoiding the problem in the first place should actually produce more readable, more easily maintainable code. What would you rather debug, code that references EMP_ID or code that references COMPANY_ASSIGNED_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER

Comment: You'll have to wait (or raise SR) on a new driver version. And BTW  the `DriverVersion 21.1.0.0.0 (ojdbc8.jar)` seems to trigger the same exception `Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call` ...

Comment: You seems to be exceptionally lucky @EdStevens, never getting `ORA-00972`;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - Nope. Never.  In over 40 years in IT,  I've _never_ needed (or wanted) an object name anywhere near that long.  Chalk that up to sane, well thought out, documented, rigorously applied naming standards.

Answer (score 3):

The `setSchema` seems to be *forgotten* in the long identifier change (and it seems you'll have to open SR with Oracle to get it work)

Contrary to that the *basic usage of long identifiers* (inclusive the binding by name) in `JDBC` seems to work fine.

Example

```
 def rs = stmt.executeQuery("select COL1, LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGE_NAME from LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGE_NAME.LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGE_NAME")
 
 while(rs.next())
 {
   println "col1= ${rs.getInt('COL1')} col2= ${rs.getInt('LAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGE_NAME')}"
 }
```

Tested with DB Version 19.3.0.0.0

DriverVersion 19.3.0.0.0  and 21.1.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

From your [documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA):

> The following list of rules applies to both quoted and nonquoted identifiers unless otherwise indicated:
>
> 1. The maximum length of identifier names depends on the value of the `COMPATIBLE` initialization parameter.
>
>    - If `COMPATIBLE` is set to a value of 12.2 or higher, then names must be from 1 to 128 bytes long with these exceptions:
>
>      - Names of databases are limited to 8 bytes.
>      - Names of disk groups, pluggable databases (PDBs), rollback segments, tablespaces, and tablespace sets are limited to 30 bytes.
>    - If `COMPATIBLE` is set to a value lower than 12.2, then names must be from 1 to 30 bytes long with these exceptions:
>
>      - Names of databases are limited to 8 bytes.
>      - Names of database links can be as long as 128 bytes.

You need to check the `COMPATIBLE` initialisation parameter and if it is set below `12.2` then you are limited to 30 bytes.

Comment: I didn't include those details as I considered them redundant, but I just updated the question with this information, the compatible version is already 19.0. Still no success here.